# Colorbar for errorbar on matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a 1D array for some quantity, say T. I have data points (X, Y) to be plotted with errorbars and colorcoded with T.

I am plotting errorbars as:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.pylab as pylab
import matplotlib

X = np.linspace(0, 10, 50) 
Y = np.random.normal(0, 1, 50)                                                                                                               
E = np.random.normal(0, 0.1, 50) 

norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=0.5)
c_m  = matplotlib.cm.jet
s_m  = matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=c_m, norm=norm)
s_m.set_array([])

plt.figure()
for i in range(0, len(Y)):
    plt.errorbar(X[i], Y[i], color=s_m.to_rgba(E[i]), yerr=[E[i], E[i]], capsize=3, ls='none')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

This doesn't seem to work. Says :

```
err must be [ scalar | N, Nx1 or 2xN array-like ]
```

For plt.plot, if I have say N curves, each with M points, and I have to colorcode each curve by T, (dimensions: X[M], Y[N][M], T[N])

I do the following:

```
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(
vmin=0,
vmax=32)

# choose a colormap
c_m = matplotlib.cm.jet
# create a ScalarMappable and initialize a data structure
s_m = matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=c_m, norm=norm)
s_m.set_array([])

plt.figure()
for i in range(0, N):
    plt.plot(X, Y[i], color=s_m.to_rgba(T[i]))
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

This scheme works for plot! But does not seem to work with errorbar and 1D arrays.

However, I am not really sure how far the comparison is good since array dimensions are different in plot (2D) and errorbar (1D) case.

EDIT:

Got the solution. It does not relate to colorbar at all. Just that yerr array needs 2XN array.

Hence yerr=[[E[i]], [E[i]]] fixes it.

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean  by "s_m.to_rgba(T) for color argument". I would suggest you provide a working solution using plt.plot which would make it clear how you use it. And then we can extend it to the errorbar.

Comment: Added the process.

Answer (score 1):

I still don't see the problem. Replacing `plt.plot` with `plt.errorbar` is working just fine:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
import matplotlib.cm
import numpy as np

N=3
x=np.arange(10)
Y = np.random.rand(len(x),N)
a = np.ones_like(x)*0.1
T = np.array([5,12,27])

plt.figure()

norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=0,vmax=32)
# choose a colormap
c_m = matplotlib.cm.jet
# create a ScalarMappable and initialize a data structure
s_m = matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=c_m, norm=norm)
s_m.set_array([])

for i in range(0, N):
    plt.errorbar(x, Y[:,i], yerr=[a,a], color=s_m.to_rgba(T[i]),  capsize=3, ls='none')
plt.grid()
plt.grid()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. However, for errorbar case, I have 1D array for X, Y. For plot, I have 2D array for data. Hence I was trying to use the code of latter into former. Sorry for not making it clear before. I have edited the question now.